# outgoing IVR through asterisk-java

Tags: java, sip, text-to-speech, asterisk, ivr

I am building simple outgoing IVR with Asterisk and asterisk-java
I installed Xlite soft phone in two different computers (A and B) in same network and setup them on asterisk and I can call them successfully 
Here is my asterisk-java code

```
public class PhoneUtility {

    private static ManagerConnection instanceManagerConnection;

    private static ManagerConnection getManagerConnectionInstance() {
        if (instanceManagerConnection == null) {
            ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new
                    ManagerConnectionFactory("192.132.0.01", "admin", "amp111");
            instanceManagerConnection = factory.createManagerConnection();
        }
        return instanceManagerConnection;
    }

    public static boolean phoneCall() {
        try {
            ManagerConnection managerConnection = getManagerConnectionInstance();
            OriginateAction originateAction;
            ManagerResponse originateResponse;

            originateAction = new OriginateAction();
            originateAction.setChannel("SIP/ivan");
            originateAction.setCallerId("1234");
            originateAction.setContext("ivr-ext");
            originateAction.setExten("1235");
            originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1));
            originateAction.setActionId("2");
            originateAction.setTimeout(300000l);
            originateAction.setAsync(new Boolean(false));

            // connect to Asterisk and log in
            managerConnection.login();

            AsteriskServerImpl asteriskServer = new AsteriskServerImpl(managerConnection);
            AsteriskChannel asteriskChannel = asteriskServer.originate(originateAction);

            // Play a prompt by text to speach 


            Character dtmf = asteriskChannel.getDtmfSent();
            if (dtmf.equals("1")) {
                managerConnection.logoff();
                return true;
            } else {
                managerConnection.logoff();
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I execute the code (invoke phoneCall() ) in computer A to call computer B 
when the code is executed in computer A  my soft phone rings in computer A first and I have to answer on soft phone computer A then computer B soft phone rings, 
How can I automatically open a channel for computer A through coding (I don't want to have soft phone in computer A at all)

Comment: is your code available for download?

Answer (score 0):

You Can make phone B rings first and if answered then the phone A rings (IVR-Extension which will be replaced by IVR APP which will auto-answer) by:

## Swapping the CallerID with Extension like below:

```
        originateAction = new OriginateAction();
        originateAction.setChannel("SIP/1235");
        originateAction.setCallerId("1235");//put the target extension here
        originateAction.setContext("ivr-ext");
        originateAction.setExten("1234"); //put IVR-extension  here
        originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1));
        originateAction.setActionId("2");
        originateAction.setTimeout(300000l);
        originateAction.setAsync(new Boolean(false));
```